# Do Monster Surges Count as a Prevented Gate Opening for the Purpose of Increasing the Deep One Rising Track?

Tags: arkham-horror

Does a token get added to the Deep One Rising Track for a Monster Surge?

Rule in question:
"There are two primary ways for the Deep Ones rising track to advance.  Each time a Gate is prevented from opening, such as by an elder sign token, or an investigator ability, add one uprising token to the Deep One Rising track"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the official ruling is that a monster surge is not a gate opening, it is an effect that occurs instead; and it does not cause a Deep One token to be added.

[This page on the Arkham Horror wiki](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Deep_Ones_Rising_track) also suggests that adding a Deep One token is an event that occurs at a different time than a monster surge, and offers some additional explanation of the difference!

Answer (score 4):

A deep one rising token is added when a gate is prevented from opening. A monster surge occurs when a gate opens on a location that has a gate already. So really, the second gate isn't prevented from opening, as it's the opening that causes the monster surge.

Gate are (at the moment at least) really only prevented from opening by seals on the board or Kate Winthrop's ability.